# Can I add Google Cast button without using ActionBarAcitivty?

Tags: android, google-cast

I have a project using `android.app.Fragment` and `android.app.Activity`, and now I want to add Google Cast button to it.

The documents say I should use `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`, but if I do so I also need to rewrite almost whole my project from `android.app.Fragment` to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

I just need Cast button, and it does not make sense to force such huge change. Is there a way to add Google Cast button without using ActionBarAcitivty? Thank you!

Comment: **"The documents say..."** : Which documents are you referring to?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender

Comment: I have a cross-port of `mediarouter-v7` that works with the native action bar: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-mediarouter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the official Cast SDK and the official mediarouter-v7 library, you cannot get around that.

Comment: Folowing this official tutorial,  which is stating that FragmentActivity can be used, I am unable to get the ChromeCast button to show up in the ActionBar of the app, instead, it shows up as chjCast in the options menu (due to this setting in main.xml/ menu/ item: android:title="chjCast"). Can someone please confirm that FragmentActivity may be used, or whether ActionBarActivity is the only option? Whatelse may prevent the button from showing up? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter.html#cast-ui